# NuGet version trees

Tags: nuget

What is the correct/accepted way of using NuGet with multiple version trees? We have a product that is in its 2.12 version, and it is continuously being worked on, generating newer versions belonging to the major number 2. At the same time, we have version 3.5 also being actively worked on with other feature set and schema. If I use the same NuGet package ID, users will always get the 3.5 version by default.

Should I simply create different package IDs for each one of the major project versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your situation I see two possible solutions. Either you go with different package IDs or you can constrain the clients to use a specific version range by hand editing the packages.config file.

In the packages.config you can set a [version constraint](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions):

```
<packages>
    <package id="SomePackage" version="2.1.0" allowedVersions="[2,3)" />
</packages>
```

This would make the client get the latest 2.x version, but never upgrade to a 3.x version.

Answer (score 1):

This page: http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pre-Release%20Packages should help you out here. In a nutshell a package tagged as `2.12` will be classed as stable, but a version with letters in, e.g. `3.5beta` is counted as a pre-release version and can only be installed using the `–Prerelease` flag.

Comment: Thank you. That helps while the higher version is in beta but I have a situation where both major versions 2 and 3 are in production, they have different feature sets and db schemata, and they evolve on their own. One answer would be, well that is not a best practice, but that's the situation I am in.